# Use OSMnx to evaluate the travel time depending on the OSM highway=* key: maxspeed. Possible?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm working me throu the impressiv OSMnx jupyter notebook of gboenig, I'm a MA Architecture Student from Germany and would like to use some Code to bring some fundametal Arguments to my MasterThesis, so I tried a lot and I'm very happy with the possibilities and the results. But there is one scenario that i want to evaluate:

First, all of my questions based on the osmnx-examples from Geoff Boeing (https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/tree/master/notebooks) so I don't post code snippets because there are no changes at the moment.

My idea is to analyse the impact of changing the maxspeed in some streets to raise the traveltime and force the driver to use another way throu the area, so that the lineare distance isn't the fastest way.

For this I made 2 OSM Files with JOSM, one with the current status and one with my changes.
To simplify I have the picture below:

[Shortest - Fastest Way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8MpH.jpg)

The Red Vector is the shortest way, but with the parameter maxspeed from OSM the blue one could be the fastest, and I would like to analyse witch ways I have to manipulate to get the result I'm looking for.

From the OSMnx-Examples Notebook I know the Route function, witch reacts to oneway streets and on the other Hand I know the Isometric Workflow from the Example Notebook, where I can set the travel_speed, but is there a way to use the maxspeed key from highway?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality to [calculate edge travel times](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.speed.add_edge_travel_times) is available as of OSMnx v0.13.0. You can then use these new edge travel time attributes to solve network shortest paths by travel time rather than distance.

Comment: How do I get A to B travel time in minutes? Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74065265/osmnx-i-want-to-get-the-time-distance-of-the-routes-in-minutes