# OSMnx I want to get the meter distance of the routes in minutes

Tags: python, django, osmnx

Right now I have in meters, how do I convert them to minutes?

```py
orig_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=fromLatLng[1], Y=fromLatLng[0])
dest_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=toLatLng[1], Y=toLatLng[0])
                            
# gets route in meters
pathDistance = nx.shortest_path_length(G, orig_node, dest_node, weight='length')
print('pathDistance: ', pathDistance)
```

Here is an example of what it printed from one of my route distances.

> pathDistance:  3192.146999999999

---

### Here are some more information:

I don't know how much 3192.146999999999 Meters are in minutes. It would be hard to know when roads got different speed limits and also traffic lights.

The vehicle type I'm using is Motorcycle or car, but I think I will mostly use Motorcycles, I don't even think I will use car, but maybe I will.

I'm also doing this in Django, so not sure if Django would make this any easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving shortest paths by free-flow travel time is explained in the [docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.speed) and the OSMnx [usage examples](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples). You can also find examples here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62159152/7321942). If you `add_edge_speeds` and `add_edge_travel_times`, you can solve shortest paths weighted by `travel_time` (in seconds).

Comment: Now I get **pathDistance:  10769.751000000002**.
**travel_time in minutes;  14**. So 10769.751000000002 meters takes 14 minutes. Here is another one **pathDistance:  2125.961**.
**travel_time in minutes;  3**. Here 2125.961 meters takes 3 minutes, that's kinda fast.

Comment: I used Option 1.

Comment: I didn't realise until now that `pathDistance =  nx.shortest_path_length(G, orig_node, dest_node, weight='length')`and `travel_time = nx.shortest_path_length(G, orig_node, dest_node, weight='travel_time')` looks similar, the only difference is the `weight` and variable name. I just looked at Option 1 blindly and had no idea really what I was doing.